# Page not found on action page when Using ZendFramework in EC2 linux

Tags: apache, zend-framework, amazon-ec2

I just set up a lamp stack in my ec2 image and now I am trying to use ZendFramework 1.11.12 in it.

So here is what I have done so far:

```
1. Go to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and change all 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All'. Restart apache;
2. Set up an alias for zend_tool: 'alias zf=/path/to/bin/zf.sh'. I use zf for it;
3. Use 'zf create project xxx' to create a project. Here I can go to the Index controller by entering 'ipAddress/xxx';
4. Use 'zf create action test Index' to create a action called 'test' in the Index controller. And I failed on this step ... ...
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

just missed a dummy part on the url... ... never mind. So the syntax of the url in Zend is like this: ipAdress/controller/action. And I missed the controller before the action. That explains the answer.